# How to switch between different templates depending on params in $stateParams with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, parameters, angular-ui-router

I'm building an app with Angularjs and ui-router. My structure is a nested states one like this.

```
.state('ls.resource', {
  url : '/:resource',
  abstract: true,
  template: "<div ui-view></div>"
})
  .state('ls.resource.id', {
    url: "/{id:int}",
    abstract: true,
    template: '<div ui-view ></div>'
  })
    .state('ls.resource.id.view', {
      url: '/{id:int}',
      templateUrl: '/view_location.html',
      controller: '...'
    })
```

Now, I would like to switch between different templates but in the same state.
For example:

```
.state('ls.resource.id', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
        switch ($stateParams.resource) {
          case 'location': 
             return '/view_location.html';
             break;
      controller: function($stateParams) {
        switch ($stateParams.resource) {
          case 'location': 
             return 'LocationCtrl';
             break;
})
```

when the resource is 'location' and something else if different. (This solution doesn't work).

If you have ideas to fix this? I'm listening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266261/angular-ui-router-dynamically-create-template-using-stateparams-and-nested-temp)

Comment: @manishrw. I've already looked at this post but this was not exactly what I was expecting. In my case, the use of nested views has more cons than pros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding `controller` for state on conditionally in your state, you should use `controllerProvider` option there instead of `controller`, basically thta will return `controller` name for that state.

Also make sure you should close `switch`, `templateUrl` & `controller` function with `}`

**Code**

```
.state('ls.resource.id', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
         switch ($stateParams.resource) {
           case 'location': 
             return '/view_location.html';
             break;
           default: 
             return '/view_default.html';
         }
      },
      controllerPrivider: function($stateParams) {
        switch ($stateParams.resource) {
          case 'location': 
             return 'LocationCtrl';
             break;
          defautlt:
             return 'SomeDefaultCtrl' //should return some controller name
        }
      }

})
```

Comment: Perfect solution! THX Pankaj

Comment: @Okyne Glad to help you..Thanks :)